# Is it possible to automate generation of wrong choices from a correct word?

Tags: java, dictionary

The following list contains 1 correct word called "disastrous" and other incorrect words which sound like the correct word?

```
A. disastrus
B. disasstrous
C. desastrous
D. desastrus
E. disastrous
F. disasstrous
```

Is it possible to automate generation of wrong choices given a correct word, through some kind of java dictionary API?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing related in java API. You can make a simple algorithm which will do the job.

Just make up some rules about letters permutations and doubling and add generated words to the `Set` until you get enough words.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of algorithms for matching words by sound  - 'soundex' is the one that springs to mind, but I remember uncovering a few when I did some research on this a couple of years ago. I expect the problem you would find is that they take a word and return a value that represents how the word sounds so you can see if two spellings sound similar (so the words in the question should generate similar values); but I expect doing the reverse, i.e. taking the value and generating similar sounding spellings, would be quite hard.